# How to get the Mediation report from AdmobMediation using PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, adsense-api, mobile-ad-mediation

I'm using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to get the AdmobMediation report remotely from our servers

Every thing works fine, except that the response report is only related to the "Admob Network", not the "Mediation report"

so as a result, the metrics are Incomplete

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to get Mediation report instead of only Admob Network report using the SDK?
2. Is there a way to download a saved report we made on "Admob dashboard" using the php SDK?

```
$startDate = '2019-04-01';
$endDate = '2019-04-09';
$AppId = 'xxxx';
$accountId = 'xxxx';

/*
    Create the client
*/
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

/*
    Authentication
*/
$client->setClientId('xxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxx');
$client->setRedirectUri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
$refreshedAccessToken = $client->refreshToken('xxx');
$client->setAccessToken($refreshedAccessToken);

/*
    Create the service
*/
$service = new Google_Service_AdSense($client);


/*
    Get the result
*/
$metrics = array(
    'AD_REQUESTS', 'VIEWED_IMPRESSIONS', 'IMPRESSIONS_RPM', 'CLICKS', 'REACHED_AD_REQUESTS',
    'IMPRESSIONS_CTR', 'COST_PER_CLICK', 'AD_REQUESTS_RPM', 'EARNINGS'
);
$filter = array(
    'APP_ID==' . $AppId
);
$optParams = array(
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'metric' => $metrics,
    'dimension' => 'DATE',
    'sort' => '+DATE',
    'filter' => $filter,
    'useTimezoneReporting'=>true
);
$result = $service->accounts_reports->generate($accountId, $startDate, $endDate, $optParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

An [AdMob API](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started) could be used for this purpose.

Currently there are:

- [network](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.networkReport/generate)
- [mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.mediationReport/generate)

reports available.

The PHP related sources:

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/AdMob